# How to login into SonarQube in my local box

Tags: java, maven-3, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

I installed the SonarQube 3.7 in my localbox for Maven Projects (Maven 3), I can able to run the sonar and see the metrics. But i could not able to Log In as administrator in localhost:9000, what are the default login credentials for SonarQube after installation?

And also i dont see the 'Settings' link on the top bar!

Comment: Use admin for both username and password.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Documentation updated: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade (credentials: admin/admin). You'll see the "Settings" link once you've logged in as a System administrator.

Comment: Doesn't work for SonarQube 6.

Comment: Worked on SonarQube 5.6.6 User: admin, password: admin.

Comment: Thanks..It helped a lot

Comment: This worked on 7.9

Comment: User: admin, password: admin. Worked for me too.

Comment: Link is broken.